# Django Queryset with filtering on reverse foreign key

Tags: django, model, filter, django-queryset

I have the following Django model:

```
class Make:
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MakeContent:
   make = models.ForeignKey(Make)
   published = models.BooleanField()
```

I'd like to know if it's possible (without writing SQL directly) for me to generate a queryset that contains all `Make`s and each one's related `MakeContent`s where `published = True`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Django doesn't support the `select_related()` method for reverse foreign key lookups, so the best you can do without leaving Python is two database queries. The first is to grab all the `Makes` that contain `MakeContents` where `published = True`, and the second is to grab all the `MakeContents` where `published = True`. You then have to loop through and arrange the data how you want it. Here's a good article about how to do this:

http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/

Comment: see the prefetch_related() method to have it streamline the two queries you mention.

Answer (score 75):

Yes, I think you want

```
make = Make.objects.get(pk=1)
make.make_content_set.filter(published=True)
```

or maybe

```
make_ids = MakeContent.objects.filter(published=True).values_list('make_id', flat=True)
makes = Make.objects.filter(id__in=make_ids)
```

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't work. It gets all MakeContents for *one* make, where MakeContents for all Makes is needed. _set works for a single object but not for a queryset.

Comment: What's the point of adding `flat = True` ? The ids will already be unique by definition, and ensuring again that they are unique might require some additional computation.

Comment: pintoch, flat=True does not offer anything related to uniqueness. It only causes the return of single values, rather than tuples when only a single field is requested.

Comment: I believe `make.make_content_set` should be `make.makecontent_set` in the newer versions of Django (I'm using 2.2).

Answer (score 54):

I know this is very old question, but I am answering. As I think my answer can help others. I have changed the model a bit as follows. I have used Django 1.8.

```
class Make(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MakeContent(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, related_name='makecontent')
    published = models.BooleanField()
```

I have used the following queryset.

```
Make.objects.filter(makecontent__published=True)
```

You should use `distinct()` to avoid the duplicate result.

```
Make.objects.filter(makecontent__published=True).distinct()
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: when there are multiple MakeContent pointing to the same Make, this will duplicate the Make entries. Something like `select from make right join makecontent on make.id=makecontent.make_id` with multiple rows in MakeContent having the same `make_id`

Comment: You can use Make.objects.filter(makecontent__published=True).distinct()

Answer (score 18):

Let me translate Spike's worded answer into codes for future viewers. Please note that each 'Make' can have zero to multiple 'MakeContent'

If the asker means to query 'Make' with **AT LEAST ONE** 'MakeContent' whose published=True, then Jason Christa's 2nd snippet answers the question.

The snippet is equivalent to

```
makes = Make.objects.select_related().filter(makecontent__published=True).distinct()
```

But if the asker means to query 'Make' with **ALL** 'MakeContent' whose published=True, then following the 'makes' above,

```
import operator
make_ids = [m.id for m in makes if 
    reduce(operator.and_, [c.published for c in m.makecontent_set.all()] ) 
]
makes_query = Make.objects.filter(id__in=make_ids)
```

contains the desired query.

Comment: I think only this answer stick to the question

Comment: This is what I want, but I'm wondering if there's a performance penalty for selecting all then distinct()

Comment: This filters `m.makecontent_set` in code (not to mention fully formed objects) instead of the database, which is an extremely extremely extremely bad practice. You should basically never do this.

Answer (score 3):

One more time, it is not clear what was the question, but if it was desired that all related MakeContent objects must have been published this can work:

```
Make.objects.exclude(MakeContent_set__published=False)
```

And if at least one of them (as it was in other answers):

```
Make.objects.filter(MakeContent_set__published=True)
```