# Retrieve all related records using values_list or similar

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 Models: `Album`, `Picture` and `PictureFile`, linked by `Picture.album` and `Picture.pic_file`

I'd like to do something like the following, and end up with a list of PictureFile records:

```
pic_files = Picture.objects.filter(album_id=1).exclude(pic_file=None).values_list('pic_file', flat=True)
```

The above just seems to spit out a list of `pic_file_id`s however I'm wondering if Django provides a built in way to handle this or if I simply need to loop through each and construct the list myself?

Comment: So you want to retireve all the `PictureFile`s associated with any of your `Picture`s? What if two `Picture`s have the same `PictureFile`?

Comment: I suppose I would like the `PictureFile` list to be unique, however it's not terribly important for what I'm going to do with it.

Comment: Why don't you just want to get a list of all `PictureFile`s? You need only ones actually used or any other reason?

Comment: Oh sorry I guess my example code is not accurate, I'm actually querying using a specific queryset of Picture, I shall update it!

Comment: I think that's what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438134/603094

Comment: Yeah that's what I was probably going to end up trying, however I thought I'd see if there was a more direct way, perhaps something which is able to make use of `select_related()` in order to only hit the DB once.

Comment: What can be more direct than using (in your case) `picture_file_set`?

Comment: Well `select_related('pic_file')` would perform a single DB query and all desired PictureFile records would be cached. The answer you linked requires 2 separate queries.

Comment: Apologies I think I haven't read it properly, totally missed the `pic_file_set` aspect of that answer, unfortunately it's not well explained there, but thanks! I'll give it a try now :)

Comment: Are you sure? I mean, have you tried it? Well, I'm not sure, but it seems to me that this doesn't require two queries.

Comment: The `_set` thing is mentioned in the first part of the introductory tutorial and also in the tutorial on queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: Well I ran a bunch of timeit tests, and it seems `values_list` comes out ahead of `select_related()` and then looping to compile the list. I don't think `_set` applies to my situation though as I'm going from the many to one, rather than from one to many which `_set` seems most useful for. Still can't help feeling that there should be a way to efficiently pull the list of related models from the queryset from `select_related()` without resorting to looping, however maybe such a feature simply does not exist.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `_set` will be helpful only when you have a single object, that's my bad. The second code snippet from that answer does what you need and it performs _one_ query with a subselect in `WHERE`. I think it's superior to looping (or using generator expression).