# Order the related set in a many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

Lets say I have a setup like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.CharField()

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    website = models.URLField()

class ProductPrices(model.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
    price = models.FloatField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField()
```

and then I have a page on which I would like to list all products, which shops they can be found at and to what prices. Is it possible to have the prices for all (or just some) products sorted, without using:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-price']
```

on **ProductPrices**?

That is, in my view I would want to do something like this (sort the productprice_set, on the price column):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    for product in queryset:
        product.productprice_set.order_by('-price')
        # Have also tried the following, without any result
        product.productprice_set = product.productprice_set.order_by('-price')
return queryset
```

To clarify: I want to sort the prices for each product, not the products based on the prices. But I want to do this by going "through" the products way.
I want 'productprice_set' ordered, and not 'product'.

Comment: Er, the "something like this" you want to do is *exactly* how you would do it (except you would use the actual name for the reverse relation, `product.productprices_set`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Edited my post to the correct now. But it still doesn't work. The prices, for products with more than one price, remains unchanged whether I have 'price' or '-price'.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. You need to actually do something with the queryset that you're ordering there: currently that code retrieves an ordered queryset, then throws it away. Usually you would iterate through it in some way.

Comment: Well, it's in a view and I want it to be sent to the template in this way. I updated the post again and added a clarification at the end.
It's not the queryset I want ordered, it's the 'productprice_set' part within the queryset.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437335

Answer (score 0):

That syntax does not somehow modify the relationship so that subsequent calls return an ordered queryset: it returns the ordered qs then and there. Subsequent calls will have the default ordering.

The way to do this is to use the order_by clause when you're retrieving the objects. Since you can't pass arguments to methods in the template, the way to do it is to define a method on Product which returns the ordered prices:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def ordered_prices (self):
        return self.productprices_set.order_by('-price')
```

and call it in the template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.name }}
    {% for price in product.ordered_prices %}
        {% price.price %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you've got me to understand that what I'm doing is not working, and why it doesn't. And also a solution.
But I still don't understand one thing. If I load all data into a queryset, modify some things, then return it. Shouldn't this modified version be the one that is sent to the template?
I tried and added an attribute to each product in the for loop, which I then could access in the template. Or is it that, in my template, there is a new queryset made when I take the prices from the products? (I thought everything was loaded before, in the 'get_queryset' method.)

Comment: That is the case if you modified products. But each call to product.productprice_set is a new call to the db and therefore a new queryset. I guess an alternative way of solving this is to stick with your original loop in the view, but store the ordered prices in a new attribute on each product. That would work, but I think my original solution is cleaner.

Comment: Okey, I see. I like your solution, but I have a little problem with it though. It's that you add price info to the product model. I have them in two separate apps, and adding that information to the product model would make it harder to re-use the app as it is in the future. But maybe it's just me who have totally overdone/misunderstand how to separate a project into apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution now in which I don't have to modify any model, nor make any more database queries.

In my view I have now:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('price_set')

    for product in queryset:
        product.prices = sorted(product.price_set.all(), key=lambda x: x.price, reverse=true)

return queryset
```

And then in my template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.name }}
    {% for price in product.prices %}
        {% price.price %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since I'm new to using Django, I wonder if there's anything "wrong" or bad by solving it like this?

Comment: Well, this is almost the "alternative solution" I mentioned before. My only comment would be that it's better to rely on the database to do the ordering: so use `product.prices = product.price_set.order_by('-price')` as you had before.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that. However, letting the database do it will create a new query for every product. Having it in the Python code, there will be no extra queries (with the prefetch_related). Would you still say it's better to have these extra queries and let the database to the work?

Comment: Just tested them both, and debug-toolbar shows that both CPU time and query time is much lower when letting Python do the sorting. I only have 5 products of which one has prices though.