# Django many to many

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am fairly new to django and I am trying to create an app with the following models

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Group(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=3,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Department(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    ric = models.CharField(max_length=12,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Encounter(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

The user would finally be the logged in user. I am able to get a set of all Department objects for a user, but how do I get the set for all Encounters with the said set of Departments? Is there some built in way or do I just use a for loop over all the Departments?

Comment: Read through the following link. You'll find it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437609/9246099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible ways:

```
encounters = Encounter.objects.filter(
    department__in=QUERYSET_CONTAINING_DEPARTMENTS,
).distinct()
```

---

You might want to read: [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was flying over the docs, but you really need to dig deeper into the filter method. Thanks!