# Django Reverse Filter Queryset Foreign Key Example Not Working

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm loosely following the example laid out here:

[Django Queryset with filtering on reverse foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437335/django-queryset-with-filtering-on-reverse-foreign-key)

Model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Profile(models.Model):
    Days = '1st'
    Mids = '2nd'
    Nights = '3rd'
    Work_Schedule_Choices = [
      (Days, 'Day Shift'),
      (Mids, 'Mid Shift'),
      (Nights, 'Night Shift'),
    ]  
    sitename = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profiles')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    schedule = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=Work_Schedule_Choices,default=Days)
    totalusers = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(50)])
```

views:

```
def sitedetail(request):
site = Profile.objects.filter(id__in=Profile.sitename)
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'App/site-detail.html', {'profile_set': Profile.objects.all(site)})
```

When I load the page it gives a TypeError:

'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object is not iterable

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I see the same stack article referenced numerous times so I'm assuming it's Operator-Head-Space-Timing error :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: two underscores `id__in`

Comment: Ok, thank you, edited for clarity. that creates the following TypeError:'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the site:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def example_view(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.filter(sitename=get_current_site(request))
```