# How to get entry using primary key from another model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 models, "Listing" and "Watchlist". Watchlist has a primary key that is referencing Listing.
For every "Watchlist" object (that has the same user X) I want to get the according "Listing" entry in form of a QuerySet.

I really struggle with this, because I don't know how to incorporate a for-loop into a queryset request.

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="watchlists")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I don't understand very well what you plan to do for, where is your form ? Why do want to loop ? Explain me please.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437335/django-queryset-with-filtering-on-reverse-foreign-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `listing` field has `related_name="watchlists"`, we can filter using related_name like this:

```
Listing.objects.filter(watchlists__user = X) # X is a user instance.
```

Note that `__` is used for field lookups. `__user` is for user field lookup.

If `listing` field does not have any related name, we can filter using model name (`Watchlist`) with  `_set` to the referencing model.

```
Listing.objects.filter(Watchlist_set__user = X) # X is a user instance.
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.